# pipenv shell on VSCode returns WSAStartup failed: error code 10107

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipenv

I'm running VSCode on windows 10, driver Python 3.8.3 32bits.

When I type on terminal: pipenv shell

I get this error: `ImportError: WSAStartup failed: error code 10107`

Here's the complete output

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\users\camar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py",
> line 194, in *run_module_as_main
> return *run_code(code, main_globals, None,   File "c:\users\camar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py",
> line 87, in *run_code
> exec(code, run_globals)   File "C:\Users\camar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pipenv.exe_*main**.py",
> line 4, in    File
> "c:\users\camar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv_*init**.py",
> line 22, in 
> from pipenv.vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning   File
> "c:\users\camar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\urllib3_*init**.py",
> line 11, in 
> from . import exceptions   File "c:\users\camar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\urllib3\exceptions.py",
> line 3, in 
> from .packages.six.moves.http_client import IncompleteRead as httplib_IncompleteRead   File
> "c:\users\camar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\urllib3\packages\six.py",
> line 199, in load_module
> mod = mod._resolve()   File "c:\users\camar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\urllib3\packages\six.py",
> line 113, in _resolve
> return _import_module(self.mod)   File "c:\users\camar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\urllib3\packages\six.py",
> line 82, in _import_module
> **import**(name)   File "c:\users\camar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\http\client.py",
> line 71, in 
> import email.parser   File "c:\users\camar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\email\parser.py",
> line 12, in 
> from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser   File "c:\users\camar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\email\feedparser.py",
> line 27, in 
> from email._policybase import compat32   File "c:\users\camar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\email_policybase.py",
> line 9, in 
> from email.utils import _has_surrogates   File "c:\users\camar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\email\utils.py",
> line 29, in 
> import socket   File "c:\users\camar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\socket.py",
> line 49, in 
> import _socket ImportError: WSAStartup failed: error code 10107

I'd like to know how to solve this or, at least, what can I do alternatively to create a virtual enviroment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to create a new env?

in that case you can use:

```
python -m venv myenv
```

if you want to open an existing environment in a shell you have to run  "activate"
which is a file located in the myvenv/scripts folder.
Open you shell, move to the scripts dir and type activate.
You should see a new line in you shell starting with "(venv)"